# How to append the string result to servlet URL in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

In the below code there are two functions: OppSelect() function is calling another function i.e exOpp(). Now , how to get the "result" value of OppSelect() into "exOpp()" function and append to the url? Please help.

**JS:**

```
function exOpp() {

    alert("inside");

    document.forms[0].action = "/Mgmt/ExportOpp?loadData=xls&customerprofile=" + $customerIDH + "&role=" + $roleIDH + "&targetDate=" + $targetDateH + "&actualDate=" + $actualDateH;
    document.forms[0].submit();
}

function OppSelect() {

    var menu = document.getElementById('selectedServersID').length;
    alert(menu);
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < menu; i++) {

        var selectedcol = document.getElementById('selectedServersID')[i].value;
        //var selectedcol = document.getElementById('selectedServersID')[i].innerHTML;
        // alert(selectedcol);

        if (i > 0) {
            result += ',';
        }
        result += selectedcol;
    }

    alert(result);
    exOpp();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi u can pass it as parameter to `exOpp(result);`

```
    function exOpp(data) {

var urldata = data;

              document.forms[0].action = "/Mgmt/ExportOpp?loadData=xls&customerprofile="+$customerIDH+"&role="+$roleIDH+"&targetDate="+$targetDateH+"&actualDate="+$actualDateH;
              document.forms[0].submit();

        }
```

Now add urldata to urstring as u needed..

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.. how to append the data to document.forms[0].action = "/Mgmt/ExportOpp?loadData=xls&customerprofile="+$customerIDH+"&role="+$roleIDH+"&targetDate="+$targetDateH+"&actualDate="+$actualDateH;   ?

Comment: for ex as u have added "&role="+$roleIDH+ u can add like this "&role="+urldata+ to whichever parameter in the url u need to pass the value..